# Infinite scroll, which strategy is more performant?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

We are working on an infinite scroll grid in prototype wherein the scroll pane remains constant as if all elements in the grid were on the page, thus having a fluid scrolling experience. My current solution is to use a dynamically sized div on the top and bottom of the grid to account for the missing items. For some reason the further down the page I get, the less performant it gets. I know there are other solutions but I haven't had a change to dive into them yet. I thought I would give it and ask for feedback and see which of the strategies would be the best.

1) Sized divs to provide the spacing on the top and bottom of the parent containing div.

2) Place visible elements in a container and absolute position that container on where it would logically exist on the page.

3) Custom position each item in the grid.

4) Others?

Some additional information:

- There are multiple infinite containers on the same page.
- repositioning happens by row, and margins are always also calculated.

The current code:

https://gist.github.com/jwaldrip/14b412bf8e6a2ed48e5c2f7c6a4ffea6

Comment: why not just always fetch one page in advance? or two pages? computation wise that would be way less and 99% of the time no one is going to scroll as fast as they can to the bottom.

Comment: True, we already fetch the data before hand.

Comment: So let's say you have a page.. And it's 500px tall. If you always fetch two pages ahead then you will have an additional 1k px to scroll before reaching the bottom and by then two more pages will be fetched. Letting the browser determine height by Dom elements is going to be the most performant